# Selenium Webdriver wait for button text to change

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a scenario (in Ruby) where button initial text is 'Activate', once it is clicked, it takes 3-5 seconds to do what ever necessary then the button text changes to 'Deactivate'.

Because the button always exist, using following code does not help.

```
wait.until {
  driver.find_element(:id => 'changeStatus')
}
```

How can i ask webdriver to wait for 5 seconds before checking the button text after clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do a wait and look for the text instead

```
wait.until { 
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='Deactivate']")
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yep that works.  One small note, i always (As much as possible) use id instead of xpath.

Comment: I use CSS selectors looking for ID or class name primarily.  Xpaths are a little slower but are able to search for text where CSS selectors can't.  In your case I don't think there is any other option than to look for text with xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Brendan's answer is definitely correct, but I would use a more specific XPath, since the answer as stated will wait until the word 'Deactivate' appears ANYWHERE on the page.

Consider narrowing down the type of elements searched, and further narrowing down by ID. You don't say what type of element it is, so I will guess it's an anchor tag (//a), adjust as necessary

```
wait.until { 
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='changeStatus' and text()='Deactivate']")
}
```

This should speed up the search considerably