# How to wait for the text of table row to change?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the HTML below:

```
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <span>
          <span> I Will Change </span>
       </span>
```

I am trying to figure out when the text inside of the span changes and store the new text in a variable. This is what I tried:

```
 waitForClick = wait.until {
      newText = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(xpath, //path for the span with the text
 }
```

This produces a syntax error and I am not sure how to use the invisibilityOfelementswithText. How could I use this in Ruby and what is the best way to notice a change of text? I do not know what the text will change to so I cannot have a wait.until either

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The SPAN element to no longer be visible or the text to change or the text to disappear or ?

Comment: @JeffC The text inside the span to change

Comment: Please reread your question and clean up the text so it says what you intend it to mean. You're missing punctuation and words. Grammar is important on SO as we're building an online reference book so your effort and help is useful. Reading "[ask]", especially the linked pages, will help you understand the site.

Comment: @theTinMan I fixed it... it wasn't that bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver wait for button text to change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647278/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-button-text-to-change)

Comment: I think accepted answer in that question might help with your question. As to the InvisibilityOfElementWithText() method, it's looking for an element to go invisible or to be removed. I don't think that's what you want here because you are expecting the element to persist but the text contained in it to change.

Comment: @JeffC The answers in that question on stackoverflow question does not work in my question because I do not know what the span will change to. The accepted answer in there assumes you know what it changes to. All I know is the current text, not what it will change to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not ruby developer but i think that the idea needs to be something like:

```
while(driver.PageSource.Equals("I Will Change"))
{
   sleep(1000)
}
```

Comment: PageSource? That's not very specific and a sec between pollings is kinda long.

Comment: you can make it more spesific by driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'I Will Change')]").Count > 0) , the idea is until the element exist stay in loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this using `ExpectedConditions`. The text related methods are all related to finding text not for waiting for text to change. In Java there is `FluentWait` but I can't find any reference to it for Ruby. `FluentWait` allows you to write a custom wait so that you could wait for the current element with the current text to return false which would signal a text change. Other than that, you would have to implement it yourself. I don't know Ruby but the pseudocode would be like

```
timeout = 20 // seconds
while (element.text == "I Will Change" and timeElapsed < timeout)
{
    sleep(100)
}
```

Make sure you add the timeout to the code above if you implement it yourself. You don't want the expected text to be slightly off and the script get stuck and never finish.

As to the `InvisibilityOfElementWithText()` method, it's looking for an element to go invisible or to be removed. I don't think that's what you want here because you are expecting the element to persist but the text contained in it to change.